# What is the dimension of the vector space $\mathbb Q [x]$/$((x+1)^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

> What is the dimension of the ring $\mathbb Q [x]$$/$$((x+1)^2)$ as a vector space over  $\mathbb Q$ .

How to deal with this types of problems.

Comment: Can you find a basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space with basis $x^i$ for $i \geq 0$. Now you are considering a certain quotient, which means that you identify some things. Which degrees of polynomials "remain" in your case? This will allow you to find a basis and hence to solve your problem

Comment: Does the basis  consist of $1$ $+$ $(x+1)^2$. And  $x$ $+$ $(x+1)^2$

Comment: Yes. That is one basis. In the quotient we have the equality $x^2 = - 2x -1$ which means that you will only find degree $0$ and degree $1$ things.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Use the fact that $\Bbb {Q}[x]$ is an Euclidean domain and polynomial can be expressed in division algorithm form.Count the form of remainder which we can get when divisor is the polynomial $(x+1)^2$.